# Error: org.macports.checksum for port py27-setuptools returned: Unable to verify file checksums

Tags: terminal, macos, macports

I'm attempting to upgrade to MacPorts 2.3.5 on a PowerMac running OS X 10.5. The upgrade is failing with the error:

```
Error: org.macports.checksum for port py27-setuptools returned: Unable to verify file checksums.
```

More of the output:

```
$ port upgrade outdated
...

--->  Computing dependencies for py27-setuptools
--->  Verifying checksums for py27-setuptools
Error: Checksum (md5) mismatch for setuptools-28.8.0.tar.gz
Error: Checksum (rmd160) mismatch for setuptools-28.8.0.tar.gz
Error: Checksum (sha256) mismatch for setuptools-28.8.0.tar.gz
Error: org.macports.checksum for port py27-setuptools returned: Unable to verify file checksums
```

I tried to manually install it but got the same error. The manual installation came from [MacPorts Issue 43307](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/43307):

```
$ cd /opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/py-setuptools
 PowerMac:py-setuptools$ sudo curl -k -O
 https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-28.8.0.tar.gz
 Password:
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time
 Current
                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left
 Speed
 100   315  100   315    0     0    894      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--
 948

$ sudo port install py27-setuptools
 --->  Computing dependencies for py27-setuptools
 --->  Fetching distfiles for py27-setuptools
 --->  Verifying checksums for py27-setuptools
 Error: Checksum (md5) mismatch for setuptools-28.8.0.tar.gz
 Error: Checksum (rmd160) mismatch for setuptools-28.8.0.tar.gz
 Error: Checksum (sha256) mismatch for setuptools-28.8.0.tar.gz
 Error: org.macports.checksum for port py27-setuptools returned: Unable to
 verify file checksums
 Please see the log file for port py27-setuptools for details:
 /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports
 .org_release_tarballs_ports_python_py-setuptools/py27-setuptools/main.log
 To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
     http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
 Error: Processing of port py27-setuptools failed
```

I can't remove Python 2.7 because it removes SSH and some other programs I depend on. Removing SSH means I lose access to the box. I'm not sure where the SSH/Python dependency comes from. I've built OpenSSH from sources, and the dependency does not exit in real life.

How do I finish the 2.3.5 upgrade?

Comment: The download size of only 315 bytes looks suspicious and indeed [https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-28.8.0.tar.gz](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-28.8.0.tar.gz) returns an XML document containing **The specified key does not exist.**

Comment: OK, thanks. It sounds like one of their scripts needs some work. I'll keep waiting for the fix.

Comment: Did you resolve this? py27-setuptools @28.8.0 installed fine on my  iMac running 10.12.1. I'd say the upstream URL format has changed since the time of that ticket you found as it's now [this](https://pypi.python.org/packages/25/4e/1b16cfe90856235a13872a6641278c862e4143887d11a12ac4905081197f/setuptools-28.8.0.tar.gz#md5=43d6eb25f60e8a2682a8f826ce9e3f42) for 28.8.0 (found towards the bottom [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/28.8.0)). It looks unpredictable for any given version so I wonder if the portfile fetches it some other way - `pip` maybe?